# Invalid URL or resource not found imagen javafx maven

Tags: javafx, maven, notification, javafx-css, image-view

[image]estoy utilizando la libreria controlsfx 11.2.0 para dar notificaciones al momento de que el usuario inicie sesion, trato de agregarle una imagen a la notificacion pero me dice que la ruta es invalida o no la encontro, coloque la rutas similar a como lo hace scene builder si funciona asi pero tanto de esta como otras maneras no funciono, de que manera tengo que colocarlas?

Comment: Prueba de este modo: `new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("com/example/pokedb/images/cancelar.jpg"))` Por favor, para las preguntas considera poner el código como texto, no en capturas de pantalla.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, use la captura de pantalla para detallar la ubicacion de las imagenes, tendre en cuenta el poner el codigo como texto.

Comment: Depura donde está ubicando tu carpeta de recursos haciendo por ejemplo un print de `getResources()`

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: amigo ya pude hacerlo gracias a tu modo, nada mas me faltaba colocar un slash antes del com, ¡gracias!

Comment: Me alegro. Además, ten en cuenta que este es el modo más adecuado de referenciar los recursos, porque los encontrará igualmente cuando distribuyas tu aplicación. Si no manejas bien eso, puede que en fase de desarrollo todo funcione bien, pero cuando pases la aplicación a producción, algunos archivos no se encuentren porque no has manejado bien las rutas, o las has puesto manualmente y luego no se encuentran en el archivo empaquetado para distribución final.